# flask db migrate adds project name to generated script

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

When I run `flask db upgrade`, I am getting this error

```
  File "/Users/user/Development/projects/zen/zen_api/zen_api/migrations/versions/88e9c6a7b904_.py", line 23, in upgrade
    sa.Column('first_name', sa.String(length=zen_api.config.Config['NAME_LENGTH']), nullable=False),
                                             ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'zen_api' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why when I run `flask db migrate` a migration script is generated with `zen_api.config.Config[...]`. This causes the following error when `flask db upgrade` is ran

```
    sa.String(length=zen_api.config.Config["NAME_LENGTH"]),
                     ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'zen_api' is not defined
```

migration script generated

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_name', sa.String(length=zen_api.config.Config['NAME_LENGTH']), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=zen_api.config.Config['EMAIL_LENGTH']), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
```

Should I be adding `import zen_api` to the `script.py.mako`? I"m new to flask and I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do things or if there a better approach.

File structure for my project

```
/zen_api
  /tests
  /zen_api
    /migrations
      /versions
        88efjd8f_.py
    /models
```

Comment: I'm not sure what zen_api is, or why your generated migration scripts make a reference to it. If you think the code is correct, then adding the missing import will likely solve the problem, but I think the length of the field should be given as a hardcoded number in a migration script.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Thank you for the comment! The config value is initialized when the app is ran. Out of curiosity, why do you suggest hardcoding the number? Is it because if someone changes the config value, the history of the migrations becomes broken?

Comment: Yes. A variable has no place in the migration script.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg feel free to write an answer for this question and I will gladly accept it! :)